# Add class to menu items of one specific menu (nav_menu_css_class)

Tags: functions, filters

This code adds an extra class to all my menu items:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
  $classes[] = 'btn';
  return $classes;
}
```

How do I confine this filter to my main menu (in theme location 'primary-menu')?

Regards,

Daniel

Answer (score 16):

I was also trying to solve this problem and while searching for a solution, discovered that the [`nav_menu_css_class` filter actually excepts a third parameter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89934/does-the-nav-menu-css-class-filter-accept-2-or-3-arguments). This is an object containing variables related to your menu and includes the `theme_location` variable you can use to conditionally apply class names to a specific menu. You just need to ensure that you set the `theme_location` when you call [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) in your theme. 
Here's an example:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'special_nav_class', 10, 3 );
function special_nav_class( $classes, $item, $args ) {
    if ( 'primary-menu' === $args->theme_location ) {
        $classes[] = 'btn';
    }

    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: in my case, i called the menu via  `wp_nav_menu( ['menu' => 'main'] );` so the `$args->theme_location` was empty. but the `$args->name` wasn't (since i only set this..), so i went with this attribute and it works..

Answer (score 3):

I came across this thread trying to solve the same problem - this is what I've come up with. I don't know how well this performs, since it'll be called for every single menu item, but it seems menus are set up as taxonomies inside WordPress, and so you can use `has_term()` to determine if the item is in a particular menu, and `get_nav_menu_locations()` to pull back the list of which menus are in which theme location.

Modifying your code:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
    $menu_locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
    if ( has_term($menu_locations['primary-menu'], 'nav_menu', $item) ) {
        $classes[] = 'btn';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to modify your functions.php. Just go into your template file and find wp_nav_menu and add 'menu_class' to it.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary','menu_class' => 'newmenuclass' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I need a class for the menu items (li), not the whole menu (ul).

Answer (score 0):

Adding it to myself in function.php and everything will work

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);


function special_nav_class ($classes, $item) {

    $classes[] = 'nav__link';

    if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){

        $classes[] = 'nav__link-active';

    }

    return $classes;
}
```